# phpMyAdmin displays blank page after installing APC and memcached

Tags: php, centos, memcache

I am running a LAMP stack on CentOS 5.6 with PHP 5.3. I had installed phpMyAdmin and it worked. I was able to log in and do anything. Then I installed `memcached` and its PHP extension as well as APC and it’s PHP extension. I have restarted `httpd` and `phpinfo()` says that `memcache` and APC are installed and configured.

So why does phpMyAdmin now display a blank page after installing `memcache` and APC?

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini file, [tell APC to not cache the phpMyAdmin directory](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Requirements) along the lines of adding:

```
apc.filters = "-/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58961) on the official PHP site, the user `ian dot matthews at imsoft dot co dot uk` believes it to be an APC bug:

> It's because APC doesn't handle the include/require path correctly.
>   For example, an example of a typical include is:
>
> ```
> require_once './libraries/common.inc.php';
> ```
>
> APC doesn't work properly and, in my case, regards '.' as the apache
>   directory instead of the current one. Whilst this seems to be an APC
>   problem phpmyadmin could help by (1) not gratuitously using
>   require_once when require would be better and (2) using the full path
>   when possible, i.e. doing something like:
>
> ```
> require dirname(__FILE__) . '/subdir/file_to_include.php' ;
> ```

But that basically means that you should tweak parts of phpMyAdmin to compensate for APC issues. Some more practical solutions suggested by `damian dot pastorini at gmail dot com` is to add the following line to `php.ini`:

```
apc.cache_by_default = 0
```

Or disabling APC for phpMyAdmin via the Apache config like this:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
    php_admin_flag apc.enabled Off
</Directory>
```

I am suggesting the path `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` since while you have not provided details on your system install of phpMyAdmin, this is the typical location it is installed in when doing an RPM install via `yum` or even a DEB install via `apt-get`/`aptitude` in Ubuntu.